# Laravel 5.4 Multi auth - Auth::guard()->user() empty

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I've created a multi auth test in Laravel 5.4. It's using custom middlewares, custom Eloquent providers, etc. The auth flow is working, I can login in both ways. But if the user is signed in, in the home controller when I want to check the user with `Auth::user()` or `Auth::guard()->user()`, it's empty. The `Auth::guard()` is empty as well. But I don't understand, why?! It should contains the signed in user instance, shouldn't it?

Also the `$request->getUserResolver()` says that the guard is null... o.O

What did I do wrong?

[Here it is](https://github.com/SasSam/laravel-54-multi-auth-test) my test repo, if you want to check my code.

Thank you in advance!

Edit 1:

In the `\app\Http\Controllers\Employee\HomeController.php` the `Auth::guard()->user()` and the `Auth::user()` are empty.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Employee;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class HomeController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->middleware('auth.employee:employee');
    }

    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $users[] = Auth::user();
        $users[] = Auth::guard()->user();
        $users[] = Auth::guard('employee')->user();

        dd($users);

        return view('employees.home.index');
    }
}
```

Comment: Showing the relevant code here is a pretty good idea.

Comment: Last time I saw a post with a person just putting a link to their GitHub repo, GitHub was down for about an hour and the question got downvoted. True story.

Comment: @Chay22 Do you want me to explain all steps (with code snipets) in my question how I implemented the multi auth?

Comment: That's a good idea. Anyways, how about adding an 's' `Auth::guard('employees')->user();` And before jumping into that you have to make sure that your guard is reach out `login` method inside the `Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard` class to populate the session. What I mean was how'd you authenticate the user at the first place?

Comment: Lurking into your repo, I think the issue comes from the way you register provider `Auth::provider('eloquent.employee' ...)` you filled out with the driver name which should be `Auth::provider('employees' ...)` And, doesn't it need to be loaded just before `AuthServiceProvider` resolved, like registering the provider inside `AppServiceProvider` instead?  Dunno...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Auth::shouldUse(your_guard_name)`; 
call this in your login function

Comment: This also can be called in the constructor of the controller that is going to use the guard

Answer (score 0):

Change the driver name in the `config/auth.php` as..

```
'employees' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\UserEmployee::class,
    ],
    'customers' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Customer::class,
    ],
```

Comment: Why should I do that? That's my custom driver with custom conditions for auth.